# How to cache an (almost) read-only Flask web app?

Tags: python, caching, optimization, flask

I have a Flask web app that has **no registered users**, but its database is updated daily (therefore the content only changes once a day).

It seems to me the best choice would be to cache **the entire website** once a day and serve everything from the cache.

I tried with [Flask Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/), but a dynamic page is created and then cached *for every different user-session*, which is clearly not ideal since the content is always the same no matter who's browsing the website.

Do you know how can I do better, either with Flask Cache or using something else?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use an in-memory SQLite database? Will look and feel like any regular db, but with memory access speeds.

Comment: Ah! That's clever, as long as the database fits in memory... but I might as well go with Redis at this point. My hope was to find some caching extension that does the kind of full-caching I wanted. Will accept if nothing better comes out ;)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago, I wrote an in-memory database which I called [littletable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/littletable/). Tables are represented as lists of objects. Selects and queries are normally done by simple list scans, but common object properties can be indexed. Tables can be joined or pivoted.

The main difference in the littletable model is that there is no separate concept of a table vs. a results list. The result of any query or join is another table. Tables can also store namedtuples and a littletable-defined type called a DataObject. Tables can be imported/exported to CSV files to persist any updates.

There is at least one website that uses littletable to maintain its mostly-static product catalog. You might also find littletable useful for prototyping before creating actual tables in a more common database. Here's a link to the [online docs](http://pythonhosted.org//littletable/).